# H2 database console, how the setting -webAllowOthers works?

Tags: h2

I'm starting H2 console from spring:

```
<spring:bean id="H2WebServer" class="org.h2.tools.Server"
        scope="singleton" factory-method="createWebServer" init-method="start"
        destroy-method="stop">
        <spring:constructor-arg value="-web,-webAllowOthers,true,-webPort,8082" />
    </spring:bean>
```

H2 version is 1.3.160

I do not want the console to be accesible from other computers in my network.
The documentation says to use setting webAllowOthers to allow/or not to other computers.
But if i set "-webAllowOthers,false", the console is still available in my local network.
I also checked .h2.server.properties file.

How should the setting work?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to allow other computers, then  remove the -webAllowOthers:

Like:

```
<spring:constructor-arg value="-web,-webPort,8082" />
```

else keep just the -webAllowOthers

```
<spring:constructor-arg value="-web,-webAllowOthers,-webPort,8082" />
```

If setting removed, 
then it respondes with "Sorry, remote connections are disabled on this server".

Answer (score 0):

You can always use firewall rules ;) iptables on linux and such.